# How to list all users from certain user group in k2

Tags: joomla-3.4, k2, user-groups

I want to list all users from one of my k2 user groups
for example I've user group named as "social team" and wonder to list all members belong to social team user group in k2?

is that possible? How?

Comment: Where do you want to list them? in frontend I assume

Comment: yes in front-end

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to do so with K2 in a module. Look at the K2 Users module and you'll see there's an option to display a list of users belonging to a certain K2 User Group.

Here's a screenshot of how I have this setup on a Joomla 1.5 site (the settings are identical on all major Joomla releases - 1.5, 2.5 & 3.x): http://jmp.sh/3QsVCwf

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching and there is not built-in feature in k2 to do that.

However you can use a joomla compoenent called Fabrik

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/fabrik

To do it.

There may be other components that allow you to query a DB table and show results in frontend.

With fabrick it is really easy.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I wonder do it with K2 component.